# How to make CheckBox to update in MySQL with different ID

Tags: html

I work on project for task, that is aplication which have input for enter task in database(MySQL) and after that show that input in web. Now I have check box for each ID from MySQL. I want make if check box is checked press button and update in MySQL task is over, but problem is here how tell each ID to update diferent value. I mean on Task is "Over" or task is "Not_Over".

Comment: Do you have some code

Answer (score 0):

Yes Nebojsa I have.. Below you can see my code
Now I want update this in MySQL for wach ID separete

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>
 Task
 </title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "123456789";
 $db="task_db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

  // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  } 
  echo "Konektovan na bazu MySQL<br>";
  ?>
  <a href="add_a_new_task.php">ADD a new Task</a> | <a 
  href="review_tasks.php">Show Task</a> | <a 
  href="completed_tasks.php">Ended Task</a>
  <hr>


 <?php

  $Select = "SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE done LIKE 'NE'";
  $Result = $conn->query($Select);


  echo '<table align="center" style="width:65%" border="2">
  <tr>
   <th>O.R.</th>
   <th>Name and LastName</th> 
   <th>Phone Number</th>
   <th>Places</th>
   <th>Task</th>
   <th>Notes</th>
   <th>Executes</th>
   <th>Executed</th>
   <th>Created day</th>
   <th><input type="submit" name="add_task" value="Update Tasks"></th>
   </tr>';
   if ($Result->num_rows > 0) {
   // output data of each row
     while($row = $Result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $id = $row['ID'];
      echo "<td> RB</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row["Name_and_Lastname"]."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$row["Phone_Number"]."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$row["Place"]."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$row["Task"]."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$row["Note"]."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$row["Executes"]."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$row["Done"]."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$row["Created_Date"]."</td>";
         echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='vehicle' 
         value='task'>Finish</td>";
         echo "</tr>";
         }
            } else {

        echo "<tr><th colspan='4'>0 results</th></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";



        $conn->close();

        ?>

        </body>
        </html>
```